# Cannot instantiate web service interface from client in java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, axis

I have created a webservice in apache axis 2. But I cannot instantiate the interface from my client. How to create a class to which calls the method from the interface?

guide me

Service interface:

```
                public interface BusService extends java.rmi.Remote {
                    public java.lang.String allepy(java.lang.String starting, java.lang.String ending, java.lang.String comfort) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
                    public java.lang.String cochin(java.lang.String starting, java.lang.String ending, java.lang.String comfort) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
                    public java.lang.String ooty(java.lang.String starting, java.lang.String ending, java.lang.String comfort) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
                    public java.lang.String kanyakumari(java.lang.String starting, java.lang.String ending, java.lang.String comfort) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
                    public java.lang.String kodaikanal(java.lang.String starting, java.lang.String ending, java.lang.String comfort) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
                }
```

my client coding

```
public class Servicecall {

    String luxury="";
    String start="";
    String end="";

    public void services(String start,String end,String comfort) {
     try 
     {

         String endpoint="http://localhost:8080/servicecomposition/services/BusService";

         Service service=new Service();

         Call call=(Call)service.createCall();

         call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint));
         call.setOperationName(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http","allepyReturn"));

         String ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] {start} );

     }

     catch(Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println(e);
     }
     }


}
```

In the above program I call the service from my jsp page which calls the servlet(I pass some arguements and from that servlet I call the client. But When I call the client I get this error:

```
 INFO: Server startup in 22641 ms
 java.lang.InstantiationException: com.service.BusService
```

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: this only the exception getting. Not getting full stack trace.

Comment: Use e.printStackTrace(); in your catch

Comment: No stacktrace ... no help.  Got it?  :-)